# Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed with Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy an application to windows based App Service in Azure using Azure DevOps Pipeline. For the first time, I don't see any issues and deployment got successful. But the next time, it got failed. I am getting the below error.

```
Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
To debug further please check Kudu stack trace URL : https://$XYZ-dev:***@XYZ-dev.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

When I go to the App Service in Azure Portal and from Deployment Center if I disconnect and trigger the pipeline, it get successful. But again next time it got failed.

Please anyone let us know the fix for this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try what happens when you explicitly stop the App Service before deploying to it? There are scenario's in which you need to explicitly stop the App Service before a deployment and then start it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rick. I have tried your suggestion. But not worked.